# GA tracking of 'add to cart's' on Opencart

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, opencart

I have an [online chair store](http://www.completeofficechairs.co.uk/) which is using the open source e-commerce solution [opencart](http://www.opencart.com/).

I have set up [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) for this website to track visitors, sales, referrals etc etc. Im sure most of you are more than aware of the power of GA.

I don't want to track the amount of sales the website generates, that is already set up. I want to track the amount of times people added an item to their shopping cart and then maybe (not essential) how many of them went on to buy and how many didn't.

I have scoured and posted on/in the [opencart forums](http://forum.opencart.com/), but so far no luck as to finding an answer to this.

Is anybody aware of how to do this? Or if not, any links or resources which could help me on my way.

Comment: FYI that link is `rel="nofollow"` so it won't help your SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this section of the Google Analytics docs on [Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#examples).  They use this exact example, tracking when a user places an item in the cart.  This will take care of the part about the amount of times people added an item to their cart.

You could also use Events, but Custom Variables are better suited when using the correct session-level scope (2 for us, and in the example provided).

To find out those that didn't buy, you should be able to create a report for that Custom Variable and see which ones did not convert a transaction.  This will probably be a custom report in the new interface, but I think the old GA interface showed ecommerce stuff by default with the Custom Variables.

Hope this helps!